# Zod return type of object.keysof() is not typed

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, zod

I'm trying to create a function which takes in a zod object and returns a zod enum via the `keyof()` function.

What I currently have is this:

```js
const FormSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().trim().min(1).max(20),
  password: z.string().trim().min(12).max(100),
  rememberMe: z.coerce.boolean().optional().default(false),
  redirectTo: z.string().trim().startsWith("/"),
});

type Schema<T extends z.AnyZodObject> = z.infer<T>
type SchemaEnum<T extends z.AnyZodObject> = ReturnType<T["keyof"]>;

function getEnumFromSchema<T extends z.AnyZodObject> (schema: T): SchemaEnum<T> {
  const shape = schema._type;
  return shape.keyof();
}

function test () {
  const t = getEnumFromSchema(FormSchema);
}
```

The highliter on codesandbox shows the following when hovering over `t` `const t: z.ZodEnum<["username", "password", "rememberMe", "redirectTo"]>` 
This returns an enum but TypeScript throws the error `Type 'ZodEnum<never>' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T["keyof"]>'.`

I've been trying to move forward with this, but something doesn't seem right to me, and I could not find out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it probably doesn’t translate. It means to achieve something (int this case a working example)

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with an answer supplied by ThePerplexedOne, and I found that if I do it like this, it correctly infers.

Because with their example it seems that you can't convert literals to a union. This code correctly infers the type keys and also returns an enum.

```
function getEnumFromSchema<S extends z.ZodRawShape>(schema: z.ZodObject<S>) {
  return schema.keyof();
}

function test() {
  const t = getEnumFromSchema(FormSchema);
  // t is inferred to be of type `z.ZodEnum<"username" | "password" | "rememberMe" | "redirectTo">`
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a reply to ThePerplexedOne, who has deleted their answer. It is best not to address answers to another answer author for this reason. Could you amend your answer accordingly?